# What is a good formula to calculate time intervals to throttle repeated connection attempts?

Tags: php, authentication, math, connection

In his article [Dictionary Attacks 101](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/archives/001206.html) [Jeff Atwood](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood) suggests "Limiting the number of login attempts per user" by introducing timeouts between attempts. The article suggests:

```
1st failed login    no delay
2nd failed login    2 sec delay
3rd failed login    4 sec delay
4th failed login    8 sec delay
5th failed login    16 sec delay
```

It seems simple, but I can't wrap my head around how to arrive at the actual numbers. If I count connection attempts in my code, let's say first attempt is `0`, first reconnect attempt is `1`, what do I calculate?

I tried (n*4)

```
attempt 0   0 sec delay
attempt 1   4 sec delay
attempt 2   8 sec delay
attempt 3   12 sec delay
attempt 4   16 sec delay
```

and (n^2)

```
attempt 0   0 sec delay
attempt 1   1 sec delay
attempt 2   4 sec delay
attempt 3   9 sec delay
attempt 4   16 sec delay
```

Both seem somewhat reasonable, but it bothers me that I can't figure out this simple problem.

Also: What are other sensible exponential formulas to make initial reconnects quick, but repeated attempts increasingly long?

Comment: Apart from the 0 to 2 interval (which could easily be a special case) it's just doubling the previous delay. No relationship to the attempt number I don't think

Comment: P.s this is a maths problem not a programming problem, so it's going to end up being off-topic I expect.

Comment: While this is true, I think it is very relevant in the programming context and not very much at all in the math context. Nevertheless, I was hoping there would be a simple trick so one would not need to store the delay as an actual number, but only the attempt counter.

Comment: That is just 2^n where n => 0

Comment: Just store the first delay as 2 and then store the most recent delay?